# Laravel: Check Permission for Each Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Middleware for Admin login where i am checking whether is user is admin or not. But now i want to check if an admin have permission to access the page or not. How can i do that?

My AdminMiddleware is:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->user_type=='employee')
        {
        return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }


}
```

One way is to add the following code to each and every function of every controller.

```
    if(Auth::user()->permission=='manage_employee'){
 //code here
}
else
{
//redirect to access denied page
}
```

But this is not the correct way and time consuming. Is there any other way without using packages?

Comment: You should protect them in your routes file.https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: Take a look at [Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#writing-gates).

Comment: @Daan i am already using Admin Middleware. But now i want to check permissions for those admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to use your middleware

```
Route::get('/your-url', 'YourController@yourFucntion')->middleware('admin');
```

Where `admin` is the name you register your middleware in your Kernel.php file :
to register it you have to insert this in $routeMiddleware part

```
 'admin' => MustBeAdministrator::class,
```

---

If you wan to have different kind of admin check you can edit your route to pass a variable:

```
  ->middleware('admin:employee');
```

and you can get this variable in your middleware like this:

enter this below the comment @param  \Closure  $next :

> @param string $permition

and modify your function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permition)
```

Then use your permition variable in an if statement to do whatever you want to do.

Comment: I am already using the Middleware group for authentication. After Authentication i want to check if a authenticated user has permission to access a particular page or not.